# Is there a Video Chat Plug in for GWT?

Tags: gwt, video-streaming

I was wondering if there is a video chat plug in for GWT, if not is there any advise you can give me?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You should check out webrtc. This is the holy grail for voice, video and real time data between browsers.

Here is a gwt implementation, it uses erlang for the server side though.

http://gwt-webrtc.appspot.com/

This is a simple javascript example that runs on GAE but you could even write your own wrapper 
using jsni.

http://www.webrtc.org/demo